# Kubuntu 18.04 LTS (Kernel panic after unfinished update):- Missing Sectors

Tags: kernel

---1---

Using *GParted* from a LiveUSB (using *Ubuntustudio 18.04*), I found out that there is a gap of 1813 sectors (disc 1/2 yr in use).

Could this be the cause of the Kernel panic? If yes, how to get the sectors back in the system properly.

On the hard disc:

- Windows 10 (neither fully installed by me nor used), DELLSUPPORT (unused). i.e. no dual boot here.
- 9 sdaX - in this order for X= 1,2,3,8,9,4, ua,5,6, ua, 7 --- ua = unallocated spaces, each 1 MiB
- sector gap between sda3 and sda8
- --- */dev/sda3* ends with ...29547, Name: *Basic data protection*, System: *nfts*, Mount point: */media/ubuntu/OS*, Label: *OS*, Flags: *msftdata* (data used 34.07 GiB of 221.99)
- --- */dev/sda8* starts with ...31360 [the missing 1813] N: no entry [ne], S: *grub2.core.img*, M: ne, L: ne, F: *bios.grub* (data 1 MiB; used, unused: ne)
- */dev/sda7* is labelled as *image* with 13 Gib used out of 13.12 GiB allocated. What could this image be (related to the Kernel panic issue in some way)?

Any helpful recommendations?

---2---

(1) Booting attempt stops at:
*[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]*

(2) Using the recovery menu of the version [4.15.0-20] I end up here [Repair process stops here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtW5C.jpg)

(3) Using the recovery mode of the other (of two displayed) version [4.15.0-36] I'll end up with *Kernel panic* s.a.

(4) GParted delivers
[Gparted (pic a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niRzH.jpg)
and
[GParted (pic b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luGjn.jpg)

I've marked the gap of 'missing' sectors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85706/discussion-on-question-by-joan-doet-kubuntu-18-04-lts-kernel-panic-after-unfini).

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

The user was trying to do a Software Update, and it failed.

We ran a number of tests, including `fsck`. No errors found there.

The original system that uses the [4.15.0-20] kernel will still boot. Software Updater won't run.

The failed system that uses the [4.15.0-36] kernel will not boot. It's missing initrd.img-4.15.0-36.

We did various tests, and Ubuntu may need to be reinstalled.